# get value of dinstinct object for select field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following 3 relationships:

```
class Size(models.Model):  
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return str(self.amount) + ' ' + self.unit + ' size'


class Sku(models.Model):  
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size)
    style = models.ForeignKey(Style)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.product.name

class ProductImage(models.Model):  
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products', blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return self.product.name
```

I want to show all the sizes that are foreign keys of skus as choices in a model form.

I tried this:

```
class SkuForm(forms.ModelForm):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop('product', None)
        super(SkuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        skus = product.sku_set.all()
        self.fields['size'].queryset = Size.objects.filter(sku__in=skus).values('amount', 'unit').distinct()     

    quantity = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = ('size',)
```

This puts the following values in my dropdown menu for "size":

```
{'amount':5, 'size':'cups'}
```

**How can I have it show simply:  "5 cups"?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but I can tell you that it's not correct to use `.values()` when setting the size field's queryset.

Though `.values()` will still return a queryset, it's no longer a queryset of model instances, but dictionaries instead. That won't fly with `ModelChoiceField`, which is what you're using as the form field for `size`.

You can probably get what you want by changing `label_from_instance` for the size field.

Quick example:

```
class Size(models.Model):  
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):  
        return str(self.amount) + ' ' + self.unit + ' size'

    def custom_label(self):
        # I assume this would return '5 cups'
        return '{} {}'.format(self.size, self.unit)
```

Then in your form:

```
class SkuForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        product = kwargs.pop('product', None)
        super(SkuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['size'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: obj.custom_label()


    class Meta:
        model = Sku
        fields = ('size',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I retrieved the queryset I wanted like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.product = kwargs.pop('product', None)
        super(SkuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        skus = self.product.sku_set.all()

        size_vals = []
        size_ids = []
        all_sizes = Size.objects.filter(sku__in=skus)

        for size in all_sizes:
            key = str(size.amount)+'_'+size.unit
            if any(key in d for d in size_vals):
                pass
            else:
                size_dict = {}
                size_dict[key]=size.id
                size_vals.append(size_dict)
        for size_val in size_vals:
            for d in size_val:
                id = size_val[d]
                size_ids.append(id)

self.fields['size'].queryset = Size.objects.filter(id__in=size_ids)
```